# 3-prong tamper proof screw type?

Tags: screws, bits

Anyone know what bit would fit this? I have only seen the 2-prong spanner bits...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here's what I eventually did to get the screws out:

- Used a Dremel rotary tool with a metal cutting wheel on it
- Cut slots across the head of each screw
- Used a flathead screwdriver to remove them

Hope that helps anyone who might come across this issue in the future.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

These are indeed very rare.  And old.  Google image search kept showing old radio sets.

After a lengthy search I found one source that should do the trick for you.

[Microtech Medium Domed Tri-Wing Wrench Tool Bit](https://www.bladehq.com/item--Microtech-Domed-TriWing--2914) (bladehq.com)

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I also did a lengthy search but came up empty. I also tried unsuccessfully to tap one out with a hammer and a screwdriver but it didn't budge, so you have really saved the day!

Comment: Soooo it seems the size is way off. I posted another pic in the original post above which shows how tiny the bit is compared to the screw. Any other ideas? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ns1AF.jpg                        
At this point I'm also open to the best way to remove them without a bit (drilling, tapping etc.)...? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Maybe vice-grips?

Comment: Yeah I tried that but the screw head itself is tapered so there is no way to get purchase...

Comment: No worries - Dremel to the rescue! Cut a slot in the head and used a flathead screwdriver.

Comment: RIGHT ON!  Would you please post that as an answer?   Make it longer than a comment, and simply give a step-by-step solution. 
 SE will make you wait a day or two then you should accept it.  Remember, we are building a database here that will last for years.  I often find that Google sends me to Q&A's here that were posted 6 or 7 years ago.  Most people skip over comments, remember.

Answer (score 1):

These are tri-groove screws.  Tri-groove drivers and sockets are available from McMaster Carr, among other places.  The ones pictured above are probably #10.